# Can not use apt-get

Tags: dpkg

```
root@mc:/home/sdtd# apt-get install rpm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-server : Depends: linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.38.46) but 3.2.0.64.76 is to be installed
                Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.38.46) but 3.2.0.64.76 is to be installed
 rpm : Depends: librpm2 (>= 4.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: librpmbuild2 (>= 4.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: librpmio2 (>= 4.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: librpmsign0 (>= 4.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: rpm2cpio
       Depends: rpm-common (= 4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@mc:/home/sdtd#
```

After apt-get -f install:

```
root@mc:/home/sdtd# sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic libicu48 linux-headers-3.2.0-30 linux-headers-3.2.0-31 linux-headers-3.2.0-32
  linux-headers-3.2.0-33 linux-headers-3.2.0-34 linux-headers-3.2.0-35 linux-headers-3.2.0-36
  linux-headers-3.2.0-34-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-32-generic libdumbnet1 linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic
  linux-headers-3.2.0-30-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-33-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-36-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 155 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,734 B of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.38.46); however:
  Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.64.76.
 linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.38.46); however:
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.64.76.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: run `sudo apt-get -f install` command on your terminal.

Comment: @AvinashRaj added error above

Comment: @chaos the cause of the dependency issue is dpkg, no apt.

Comment: Provide the output of `sudo dpkg -C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo su
apt-get remove --purge linux-server
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get clean
reboot
```